# How to add N+1 second using ArcPy cursor for Time Field value?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

I have a field that I would like to add one second on for each feature using field calculator and Python.  My field name is `ISSUEDTIME_NEW` I want to start my time at `00:00:00` and add one second on to each feature.

Here is what I have so far for a search cursor, however, this does not loop as expected and I want to order by another field, `ISSUEDDATE` so that my earliest time in my order field is my earliest `hh:mm:ss` in my `ISSUEDTIME_NEW` field.

i.e. since `9/10/2017 12:31:00 PM` is my earliest time in my order field then it equals `00:00:00` in my `ISSUEDTIME_NEW`

What change should I make in the code to add 1 second onto 00:00:00 for ISSUEDTIMENEW and ordering by ISSUEDDATE?

```
import arcpy
import datetime

fc = 'fc'
sql = ('ORDER BY ISSUEDDATE')
field = ('ISSUEDTIME_NEW')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field, sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        a = datetime.datetime(100, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00)
        b = a + datetime.timedelta(0,1) # days, seconds, then other fields.
        while row[0] is True:
            row [0] = b.time
        cursor.updateRow(row)`
```

`RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT ISSUEDTIME_NEW, OBJECTID FROM FC WHERE ORDER BY ISSUEDDATE]`

Answer (score 1):

The `sql_clause` parameter for the `da.UpdateCursor` is a tuple.  From the [help page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

> An optional pair of SQL prefix and postfix clauses organized in a list
>   or tuple. SQL prefix supports None, DISTINCT, and TOP.
>
> SQL postfix supports None, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY. An SQL prefix clause is
>   positioned in the first position and will be inserted between the
>   SELECT keyword and the SELECT COLUMN LIST. The SQL prefix clause is
>   most commonly used for clauses such as DISTINCT or ALL.
>
> An SQL postfix clause is positioned in the second position and will be appended to
>   the SELECT statement, following the where clause. The SQL postfix
>   clause is most commonly used for clauses such as ORDER BY.
>
> Note: DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and ALL are only supported when working with
>   databases. They are not supported by other data sources (such as dBASE
>   or INFO tables). TOP is only supported by SQL Server and MS Access
>   databases. (The default value is (None, None))

For your example, try:

```
sql = (None, 'ORDER BY ISSUEDDATE')
```

Also, the third parameter is the where, not the sql pre/post.  That is what the error message is telling you.  You need to be explicit since you are not supplying a where clause:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field, sql_clause=sql) as cursor:
```

Or provide the missing parameters:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field, None, None, False, sql) as cursor:
```

Also, your update logic looks odd.  You are resetting the a value for each row, which isn't what I thought you meant.  The `while` is also strange, and unless I am misunderstanding, not needed (or even very bad having an infinite loop).

Did you mean something like:

```
a = datetime.datetime(100, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field, None, None, False, sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        a += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
        row[0] = a.time()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Note: this is untested code.

Comment: based on the documentation, you can also just do with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field, sql_clause=('None,ORDER BY ISSUEDDATE) as cursor. There should not be a need for any additonal arguments

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- your `field` variable should be `['ISSUEDTIME_NEW', 'ISSUEDDATE']`, not just `('ISSUEDTIME_NEW')`. You can't use a field in sql_clause and not include it in the `field_name` parameter of a cursor
- sql_clause is a tuple as mentioned above.

result:

```
fc = 'fc'
sql = (None, 'ORDER BY ISSUEDDATE')
fields = ('ISSUEDTIME_NEW', 'ISSUEDDATE')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields, sql) as cursor:
    do stuff
```